# arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe cannot find -lrtlhelper

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

In Delphi 10.3.1 Rio I have created a new MultiDevice project **HeaderFoooterNavigation** from the Repository:

[image]

Then I tried to compile it for the Android platform. Unfortunately, I got these compiler errors:

```
[DCC Error] E2597 C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\ PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r17b\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: cannot find -lrtlhelper
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\ PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r17b\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: cannot find -lpcre
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\ PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r17b\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: cannot find -lcompiler_rt

[DCC Fatal Error] F2588 Linker error code: 1 ($00000001)
```

So what do I have to do to successfully compile it for the Android platform?

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the platform tools (Android JDK, SDK, & NDK)

[Installing Android JDK, SDK, NDK](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Installation_Notes#Android_JDK.2C_SDK.2C_NDK)

If you've done that, then you need to follow the steps outlined in the documentation to set up for Android

[Setting up for Android Mobile Application Development](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Android_Mobile_Application_Development)

Specifically make sure your SDK panel is setup correctly

[SDK Manager for Android SDK, NDK and Java Properties](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/SDK_Manager#Android_SDK.2C_NDK_and_Java_Properties)